# Google Analytics: Difference between Data Import & Daily upload

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can't find answers to my questions regarding to how Google Analytics Cost Data Upload works. I have a few questions:

1. Why two different upload methods? Why not just have one dimension-wide upload option?
2. Let say I upload costs using [daily upload](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDailyUploadGuide) method and after that I upload costs using [data import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData). Will data import override daily data, will that data be merged or even deleted? What will happen in this case? Will the next daily upload override data of data import?
3. If you delete uploaded data, will costs in GA report be reseted to zero?
4. Does [lifetime data storage limit per property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) also applies for daily uploads or only data import?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Btw. the answer to the first question would simply be that cost is not a dimension, it's a metric (you can add up cost and make  calculations  like ROI etc., that's not possible with dimensions). So you have two mechanisms because these are different types of data.

Comment: The reason you give for having two mechanisms in not correct in this case. Just think of cost data as a specific use case of dimension widening in Google Analytics. In both cases they do the same thing, widen on dimension values. In cost data the dimensions you can widen on and the values you can provide are set (i.e. the schema is set).

Comment: @Pete, you are right of course, cost data uploads also include dimensions. So my comment (one upvote nonwithstanding) was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dimension widening is for the generalized case whereas Cost Data is for a specific upload case (i.e. there are specific reports in GA for Cost Data). However, your question is still valid as to why there are 2 separate uploads, it doesn't look necessary but that's the way it is for now.
2. Daily upload and Data Import work independently of each other. One is not going to affect the other. You should be using daily upload for cost data since it has a set schema and reports. Data import for other data sets where you define the schema.
3. For Cost Data, if you delete the data then yes, your reports will not show any related cost data anymore (or you can just unlink the profile from the data set to accomplish the same result). For Dimension Widening, even if you delete the data set or unlink it, any data that was joined before the deletion or unlinking will stay as part of the reports, you can't remove it after the fact. This is because of differences between the two in how the data gets joined.
4. As stated in #2, these are different mechanisms, so they don't share storage. Daily upload has limits that apply to the upload (e.g. 20 appends/day, max 5MB per append). The doc you linked to clearly states what these are for each. Just treat them separately unless it is stated otherwise.

Comment: +1. Also rather important, Cutroni says that dimension widening does not apply to historical data (which I think is pretty much the point of cost data). Url here: http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/30/dimension-widening-import-data-directly-into-google-analytics/ in the section "Things to be aware of".